# Multiple buttons in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've created a button using an `SKSpriteNode` with this code:

```
quadrato_editor.name = "Ball"
node.name = "Hey"

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if quadrato_editor.name == "Ball" {
        quadrato.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

To add more buttons, I tried this:

```
if quadrato_editor.name == "Ball" {
    quadrato.isHidden = false
} else if node.name = "Hey" {
    ko.ishidden = true
}
```

But I can't get it to work. Both values `"Ball"` and `"Hey"` are true.

How can I add more than one button in `SpriteKit` using `Swift`? Forgive me if this is a rookie question, this is my first time working with `SpriteKit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to examine the `touches` to determine which button is pressed:

```
for touch in touches {
    if let node = self.nodes(at: touch.location(in: self)).first {
        switch node.name {
            case "Ball": quadrato.isHidden = false
            case "Hey": ko.ishidden = true
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it says "Switch must be exhaustive"

Comment: @xXManuelXx Oops! Edited.

Comment: sorry how can I add more than one action in "case:"

Comment: @xXManuelXx put the things you want to do on the next line.